# FileNotFoundException when creating a new ReportDocument with CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am creating a .Net CORE application to load a Crystal Report and save it as a PDF on a schedule. It have a .Net version of the application that only runs on a single, development PC. Here is my current code:

```
string executablePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string reportPath = executablePath + @"\";
Console.WriteLine(reportPath);
List<string> reportFileNames = new List<string>();

ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
```

When I execute this code in a console application, I get the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The "working" application get the same error when I move it off of the other development PC. I have the Nuget Package CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine 1.0.0 by zqb91 in the application and Crystal Reports 2020 is installed on the new development PC.

Which Nuget Package or library should I be using? The chosen package seems to be abandoned as it has not been updated in over 6 years.

==Update==

I recreated the entire application as a .Net Framework 4.8 application. I created a brand new virtual system. I installed the latest Crystal Reports runtime on that system. It wouldn't run. I made sure all of the Crystal Reports libraries were in the PATH. It wouldn't run. I installed Crystal Reports 2020 on that system. It still won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core is not compatible with .NET Crystal Reports Runtime (which requires the older .NET framework -- not the new .NET Core).

Comment: I'll try to recreate the application with an older version of .Net. Probably 4.7.

Comment: I have been trapped in meetings since you posted this solution. I'll test when when I have the breathing space.

Comment: I recreated the entire project. It would not run until I installed Crystal Reports on the system.

Comment: Created the application as a .Net Framework 4.8 application and it still won't run.

Comment: A reboot got it to run.